# imageタグで画像のサイズを実際の画像サイズからパーセントで計算させる方法は？

Tags: html

```
<p>
  <image src="hoge.png" width="50%">
</p>
```

としたところ、hoge.pngの画像サイズに対して50%ではなく
親要素(pタグ)の大きさに対して50%になってしまいました。

画像の大きさを50%にする方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

サイズを指定せず`img`要素にCSSで`zoom:0.5`ではどうでしょうか？

```
<p>
  <image src="hoge.png" style="zoom:0.5;">
</p>
```

もしくは`javascript`を使って画像のサイズを取得してサイズを固定するかですかね

Comment: zoomはFirefoxだと効かないんですよね・・・。 http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom

Comment: Chromeで見てたので他のブラウザの事を失念してました。確かにそうですね…。となるとBLUEPIXYさんがあげてますが、JavaScriptしかないんですかね…

Answer (score 1):

javascript で

```
<img src="hoge.png" onload="this.width = this.width*0.5" />
```